# Stretch container DIV over window width

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a page that can hold very big content. It could easily grow to (and over) 10.000px in width. I simply want my page to stretch along.

This should be very simple, and I can fix it with `display: table-cell`, but it doesn't 'smell' as the right answer. It feels like a hack. I think I'm missing something crucial.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8gfD/)

CSS:

```
#container { white-space: nowrap; padding: 50px; background-color: green; }
#container > div { display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 200px; } 
#container > div:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color: red; }
body { background-color: #ccc; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Why isn't the container `div` stretching to its content?
`BODY` is correctly stretched, so how do I force my container `div` to take the width of its parent or children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
#container {
    background-color: #008000;
    display: table;
    padding: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**EDITED**

```
    #container {
        background-color: #008000;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 50px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8gfD/4/)**

Comment: This is the result I want yes but using display:table(-cell) does not seem right. Why isn't my container stretching without this?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq is this what you want

Comment: YES! But Why?? So a block element will NOT stretch but an inline-block DOES? That just beats all odds!

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-x: scroll;` to `#container`. Is that what you want?

Edit: changed to overflow-x :)

CSS

```
 #container {
        background-color: green;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 50px;
        width: auto;
        overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: I think this will suit better, but make sure you use `overflow-x: scroll;` :)

Comment: No, I want my body to scroll. Not just my container. My container should stretch to the width of my content.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
  background-color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display:table;
 }
  #container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display:table-cell;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

add the line `overflow-x: scroll;` to your container-css

here is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wnv6/) as well